# asp.mvc change controller name in request path

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

In my MVC project I have a controller names ProjectController and in path it looks like /project. I want to have the path for that "/proiect" .. is there any easy way to achieve that without renaming the controller class?

Thanks, 
Radu

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish this with routing

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Misspelling",
    "proiect/{action}",
    new { controller = "project", action = "index" }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can modify the rewrite-rules in the Global.aspx file.

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "proiect/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Project", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

Comment: Can I achieve that using an attribute? I did not wanted to rewrite the mappings.

Comment: I doubt ASP MVC supports that.

Comment: Im sorry, i totally didnt. I copied the default ASP MVC mappings, as you can see by the comments, and optional id stuff. I wrote my anwser first, then added the code later on. However, i've marked yours as an awnser.